Calculate length of line drawn from major radius of ellipse that is parallel to another line on major radius
MAJOR EDIT OF ORIGINAL POST.
I'm trying to calculate p as shown in the first figure below.  I know q, b and w and the angles $\phi$ and $\kappa$ are known and are equal because the lines are parallel.  Here's what I've got so far.
$$q^2 = x_q^2 + y_q^2$$
$$p^2 = x_p^2 + y_p^2$$
where $x_q, y_q, x_p, y_p$ are lengths to the corresponding coordinates of the points on the ellipse measured from Q and P, respectively. Now if I slide q along the major axis of the ellipse over to p, then I can see that the difference in length is
$$p = q + \Delta q$$
where $\Delta q$ is shown in the blowup figure.
But
$$\Delta q^2 = \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2$$
One other piece of information I have is that the distance A to D shown in the blowup figure is equal to $w-b$.  So, if I could just get the distance from A to B ($\Delta x$) or B to C ($\Delta y$), I could solve this.  But I'm stymied.
If I need another piece of information, what is it?  It seems like there should be enough information to solve this problem. The solution needs to work for any angle $\phi$ or $\kappa$ between 0 and 180 degrees inclusive.
Edit #1:  The reason I know the length q is because Q is a focus of the ellipse.  I mention this because maybe this can somehow contribute to figuring out p beyond what I've mentioned, but at the moment I don't see how.
Edit #2.  As I look at the blowup figure some more it looks like the distance from A to B ($\Delta x$) is equal to
$$\Delta x = (w-b) - (x_p - x_q)$$
but I don't know $x_p$.



What is $\frac R{\sin\theta}$ doing here?

Do you know the equation of the ellipse?

I need to find $p$ right? Do I know the angle $\phi$?

Yes, the angle, $\phi$ is known. I was just thinking that maybe what I need is the equation of the ellipse. The minor axis length is 2R and the major axis is $\frac{2R}{\sin\theta}$. Based on the focus, Q, the equation of the ellipse is
$$\left(\frac{q}{R}\sin\phi\right)^2 + \left(\frac{q}{R}\cos\phi - \frac{b}{R}\right)^2\sin^2 \theta= 1$$

But what is the theta here? A random constant?

$\theta$ is constant.  This ellipse is produced by impinging a cylindrical jet of water of radius R at an angle, $\theta$, on a horizontal plate.  So the circular jet is projected as an ellipse onto the flat horizontal plate.  Just assume it is constant.

The coordinates of point $C$ in the figure are
$$ (p \cos\phi - w, p \sin\phi). $$
Now take the equation of your ellipse in the following form:
$$ x^2 \sin^2 \theta + y^2 = R^2. $$
Since $C$ lies on the ellipse, we can plug its coordinates into this formula:
$$ (p \cos\phi - w)^2 \sin^2 \theta + (p \sin\phi)^2 = R^2 . $$
Expand and rearrange into a quadratic equation in $p$:
$$ (p^2\cos^2\phi - 2wp \cos\phi + w^2) \sin^2 \theta + p^2 \sin^2\phi = R^2 , $$
$$
(\cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi)p^2
- (2w \cos\phi \sin^2\theta)p + (w^2 \sin^2\theta - R^2) = 0.
$$
Solve for $p$:
\begin{align}
p &= 
\frac{2w \cos\phi \sin^2\theta \pm
      \sqrt{4w^2 \cos^2\phi \sin^4\theta
           - 4(\cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi)(w^2 \sin^2\theta - R^2)}}
     {2(\cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi)} \\
&= \frac{2w \cos\phi \sin^2\theta \pm
         \sqrt{4 (R^2 \sin^2\theta \cos^2\phi + R^2 \sin^2\phi
                 - w^2 \sin^2\theta \sin^2\phi)}}
     {2(\cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi)} \\
&= \frac{w \cos\phi \sin^2\theta \pm
         \sqrt{R^2 (\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi) - w^2 \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}}
     {\cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi}.
\end{align}
Replace $\pm$ with $+$ to get the point $C$ rather than the other intersection of the same line with the ellipse.
We can find $q$ similarly by replacing $w$ with $b = R \cot \theta$.
Note that $(R \cot \theta)^2 \sin^2\theta \sin^2\phi = R^2 \cos^2\theta \sin^2\phi$
and $R^2 \sin^2\phi - R^2 \cos^2\theta \sin^2\phi = R^2 \sin^2\theta \sin^2\phi$, so
\begin{align}
q
&= \frac{R \cot \theta \cos\phi \sin^2\theta +
         \sqrt{R^2 \sin^2\theta \cos^2\phi + R^2 \sin^2\phi
                 - (R \cot \theta)^2 \sin^2\theta \sin^2\phi}}
     {\cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi} \\
&= \frac{R \cos\phi \cos\theta\sin\theta +
         \sqrt{R^2 \sin^2\theta \cos^2\phi + R^2 \sin^2\theta \sin^2\phi}}
     {\cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi} \\
&= \frac{R \cos\phi \cos\theta\sin\theta + R \sin\theta }
     {\cos^2\phi \sin^2\theta + 1 - \cos^2\phi} \\
&= \frac{R \sin\theta (1 + \cos\phi \cos\theta)}{1 - \cos^2\phi \cos^2\theta} \\
&= \frac{R \sin\theta}{1 - \cos\phi \cos\theta}.
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac pq &= \frac{w \cos\phi \sin^2\theta +
         \sqrt{R^2 (\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi) - w^2 \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}}
     {1 - \cos^2\phi \cos^2\theta}
\cdot \frac{1 - \cos\phi \cos\theta}{R \sin\theta} \\
&= \frac{w \cos\phi \sin^2\theta +
         \sqrt{R^2 (\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta + \sin^2\phi) - w^2 \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}}
     {(1 + \cos\phi \cos\theta)R \sin\theta}.
\end{align}

Considering that you know the equation of the ellipse, let the point $P$ has coordinate $(w,0)$. A straight line with angle $\phi$, passing through the point $(w,0)$ can be given the equation:
$$y=(\tan\phi) (x-w)$$
The straight line intersects the ellipse
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
at the point:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{\tan^2\phi}{b^2}(x-w)^2=1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{\tan^2\phi}{b^2}(x^2-2xw+w^2)=1$$
$$x^2\left(\frac1{a^2}+\frac{\tan^2\phi}{b^2}\right)-2\frac{\tan^2\phi}{b^2}wx+\frac{w^2\tan^2\phi}{b^2}-1=0$$
$$x(b^2+a^2\tan^2\phi)-2a^2w\tan^2\phi x+a^2w^2\tan^2\phi-a^2b^2=0$$
$$x=\frac{2a^2w\tan^2\phi\pm\sqrt{(2a^2w\tan^2\phi)^2-4(b^2+a^2\tan^2\phi)(a^2w^2\tan^2\phi-a^2b^2)}}{2(b^2+a^2\tan^2\phi)}$$
Find the $x$ that has a positive value [according to your figure]. Plug that in the equation of the ellipse to find $y$ and then calculate the distance from $(w,0)$ to $(x,y)$ to solve the problem.
If you know the focus instead, with eccentricity, then the focus is $$(b',0)\equiv(ae,0)$$ and then $b'=ae$, where $b'$ is the distance $OQ$ and plug in that back as $a=\frac{b'}{e}$ and $b=a\sqrt{1-e^2}=b'\sqrt{1-e^2}$.

Thanks.  I'll have to study this.  But I was hoping to get p in terms of q, since I already know q because it is drawn from point Q, which is a focus of the ellipse. I was hoping that if p is in terms of q, the resulting solution would be significantly simpler, but maybe that is not the case.

Since you know that $a=r/\sin\theta$ and $b=R$, why not plug them and find the length? Why need $q$?

Because ultimately I am interested in the ratio, $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$.

Also, one other question.  What happens if $\phi$ is equal to 90 degrees? It seems like the equations blow up because the $\tan(90)$ is infinity.
